# Pass a variable containing a JSON as a parameter of a function by command line

Tags: json, command-line, debian, jq, openmediavault

I need to enter a value in a **JSON** that requires an **Openmediavault** command. The command in question is this:

```
omv-rpc -u admin 'ShareMgmt' 'set'  '{"name":"120GB","mntentref":"71fdbd90-ce16-4726-ad8d-35ba8664b4c6","reldirpath": "/","mode": "775","comment": "","uuid": "fa4b1c66-ef79-11e5-87a0-0002b3a176b4"}'
```

But I need to introduce another **JSON** that I have saved in a variable. I have mounted it like this:

```
JSON_STRING=$( jq -n \
                  --arg referencia "$code_val" \
                  '{name:"120GB",mntentref:$referencia ,reldirpath: "/",mode: "775",comment: "",uuid: "fa4b1c66-ef79-11e5-87a0-0002b3a176b4"}')
```

The exit **echo $JSON_STRING**:

```
{"name":"120GB","mntentref":"71fdbd90-ce16-4726-ad8d-35ba8664b4c6","reldirpath": "/","mode": "775","comment": "","uuid": "fa4b1c66-ef79-11e5-87a0-0002b3a176b4"}
```

Now I want to build the first function and send the **JSON** that I have created by parameters, but I would not know how to do it, can you give me a hand?

I tried this way but it gives error. I have little knowledge of **Debian console commands**:

```
omv-rpc -u admin 'ShareMgmt' 'set' '{'echo $JSON_STRING'}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to access variables:

```sh
omv-rpc -u admin 'ShareMgmt' 'set' "${JSON_STRING}"
```